# Can not pull image from private docker registry which are connected through openvpn

Tags: docker, openvpn

It is Docker Mac.
My private docker registry need to be connected through openvpn.
I can connect the registry server in mac os while openvpn connection is open. But docker pull will fail.
I guess the problem is the docker virtual machine could not use the openvpn connection, and I am tying to figure a solution...
I think it is a problem about hyperkit. As it worked after I switch the drivier to vmwarefusion.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: did you use `docker login` first?

Comment: The registry does not need a login. It is a network connection problem from within the docker-machine through host-machine openvpn.

Comment: I think it is a problem about hyperkit. As it worked after I switch the drivier to vmwarefusion.